# Origen de "chinita" para referirse a la "piel de gallina"

Tags: etimología, expresiones, méxico

En el último tema que han sacado conjuntamente David Bisbal y Juan Magán ([*Bésame*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1YG24JY3yQ)), hay un verso que dice así:

> Que se ponga chinita tu piel cuando te toco

Por el contexto, está bastante claro (y que alguien me corrija si no es así) que aquí "ponerse chinita" se refiere a "ponerse la piel de gallina":

[image]

Según el DLE, este significado de "[**chinito, ta**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8pjveej)" es particular de México.

**¿De dónde viene la expresión *"ponerse la piel chinita"*?** ¿En qué regiones se usa?

Comment: Se me ocurre que puede ir por el verbo [_achinar_](https://dle.rae.es/?id=0RAvu9R|0RC8MuS): _Dicho de los ojos: Ponerse oblicuos_. En este caso, referido a la piel podría tratarse de una emulación de este movimiento pero para el caso de la piel.

Answer (score 2):

> **Descargo de responsabilidad.** Lo expuesto a continuación ha sido fruto de consultas en el CORDE, CREA, NTLLE, Fichero general de la RAE, Google Maps y otras fuentes, mezclado con un poco de imaginación por mi parte. El resultado es totalmente debatible; si alguien de México nos puede echar una mano, mejor que mejor.

---

Como has podido comprobar, la expresión *[ponerse alguien chinito](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8pjveej)* la recoge el DLE como expresión de uso coloquial en México, y significa "ponérsele a alguien carne de gallina". Pero ¿de dónde viene la expresión?

Pues tras un rato buscando en el *Fichero general* de la RAE por fin he dado con una ficha, perteneciente a unas "Notas a *Valle Negro*", de Antonio José Ballari, que dice lo siguiente:

> **Chinita:** Diminutivo de **china**, nombre con que entre nosotros vale, como aquí, a sirvienta. Originalmente indicó a la mujer india pampa. Por extensión se le aplicó a la criolla morena del pueblo, y de allí a las sirvientas llegadas del campo a la ciudad. Con todo, no es término despectivo [...]. Nuestros gauchescos le dan también a esta voz el significado de mujer querida [...]. Y en este sentido de cariño y afecto entre nosotros es muy usada esta voz.

Esta descripción aplica a Argentina, pero en el DAMER se lee en la entrada para *[china](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=china)* que en México existe la acepción de "mujer joven", significado que pudo llegar a través de Chile, donde significa "mujer del pueblo", y luego a través de Perú y Ecuador, donde significa "mujer indígena adolescente", y desde ahí pierdo la pista en el DAMER pero no es descabellado pensar que el significado se fue extendiendo hacia el norte. Veo en el CORDE usos cariñosos de *chinita* en Colombia a finales del siglo XIX ("no te enojes, por Dios, chinita mía"). Ya a finales del XX veo casos en el CREA de este uso de *chinita* tanto en Costa Rica como en Panamá.

En todo caso, yo identifico el uso de "ponerse chinita" en México como haciendo alusión a cómo las mujeres jóvenes se sienten en relación a sus primeros amores. Básicamente lo que entiendo que dice la expresión es que cuando alguien se pone chinito es como si experimentara el amor por primera vez, como cuando se es joven.

> *Algunas veces, Júbilo, sin querer, queriendo, le rozaba con la mano las piernas y a Lucha se le ponía la piel chinita.*
>
> Laura Esquivel, "Tan veloz como el deseo", 2001 (México).

Y el caso más antiguo que me he encontrado (en femenino):

> *Yo cuando veo los besos que se dan los artistas, me pongo chinita, chinita... ¡de coraje! por lo inmorales que son esas cosas. ¡Qué esperanzas que mi marido me diera un beso!*
>
> Wilebaldo López, "Vine, vi... y mejor me fui", 1975 (México).

Curiosamente en masculino se usaba incluso antes, en contextos diferentes a los amorosos:

> *Dionisio acabó de cerrar la pulquería y se fue a su casa chinito de frío [...].*
>
> Mariano Azuela, "La luciérnaga", 1932 (México).

Luego el uso de *chino, -a* como "mujer joven" y el uso de *chinito, -a* que nos ocupa debieron establecerse en México durante el primer cuarto del siglo XX como muy tarde. En Argentina el caso más antiguo que he visto es de 1870.

Answer (score 2):

Creé mi cuenta solo para opinar acerca de esto. En Puerto Rico y República Dominicana a las naranjas se les llama chinas y a las mandarinas se les llama chinas mandarinas.

En el gif que pones, la piel se pone como la de una china (naranja).

Answer (score 1):

Creo que *chinita* viene de *china* ("guijarro") por la forma de la piel "enchinada":

> [**enchinar**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=enchinar)
>
> 1. tr. Empedrar con chinas o guijarros.
> 2. tr. *Méx*. Formar rizos con el cabello. U. t. c. prnl.
> 3. prnl. *Méx*. Dicho de una persona: Ponérsele la carne de gallina.

Comment: [El habla popular en Baja California Sur: (enchinar)](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=PtUuAAAAYAAJ&q=chinita+piel+de+gallina); [Cornucopia de México](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_LRVAAAAMAAJ&dq="chinita+o+enchinada")